# Vertically position iframe inside paragraph

Tags: css, iframe

I am trying to be clever and position a FaceBook Like button iframe inside a sentence but it aligns oddly, see screengrab below.

I'm sure I'm being dense but without styling the iframe as a block element how do I re-position it?

I tried display:inline-block but it didn't respond to margin settings.  I also tried increasing the paragraph's line-height to match the iframe but that didn't help.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: not sure this is the best idea.  It they ever change something over on FB, it'll break your code.  It is generally better to have the resources you use on your server if possible.  But in any case, it's very hard to answer your question without some of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`vertical-align:middle`   did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in a DIV and adjust margin-top on the DIV.